# web scraping using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape multiple pages of website using Python, but I'm getting  ***Remote Connection closed error.***
Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
url_link = 'https://www.taneps.go.tz/epps/viewAllAwardedContracts.do?d-3998960-p={}&selectedItem=viewAllAwardedContracts.do'
LIST = []
for number in range(1,5379):
  url = url_link.format(number)
  dframe = pd.read_html(url, header=None)[0] 
  LIST.append(dframe)
Result_df = pd.concat(LIST)
Result_df.to_csv('Taneps_contracts.csv')
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I believe you need to be authentified to access the page. You haven't provided any headers.

Comment: Yes, there is no need to be authenticated,, How do I provide headers?

Comment: It seems you have 2 issue: the first is to create a scraper, for this is better to use[scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) and collect all pages locally. In a second steps you should read and 'understand' the content of the pages. Don't do all in a once, can become painfull.

Comment: why have you tagged beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 0):

For me, just using [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) to fetch the html before passing to `read_html` is getting the data. I just edited your code to

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
url_link = 'https://www.taneps.go.tz/epps/viewAllAwardedContracts.do?d-3998960-p={}&selectedItem=viewAllAwardedContracts.do'
LIST = []
for number in range(1,5379):
  url = url_link.format(number)
  r = requests.get(url) # getting page -> html in r.text
  dframe = pandas.read_html(r.text, header=None)[0] 
  LIST.append(dframe)
Result_df = pd.concat(LIST)
Result_df.to_csv('Taneps_contracts.csv')
```

I didn't even have to add headers, but if this isn't enough for you (i.e., if the program breaks or if you don't end up with 53770+ rows), try [adding convincing headers](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-fake-and-rotate-user-agents-using-python-3/#therightwaytorotateuseragentsinanyprogram) or using something like [HTMLSession](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) instead of directly calling `requests.get`...