# Replace span tags with whitespace or parse contents as new column with pandas.read_html

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape Congressional stock trades from [Capitol Trades](https://www.capitoltrades.com/trades). I can scrape the data, but the column that contains stock tickers has a span tag that separates company names from company tickers. `pandas.read_html()` removes this span tag, which concatenates company names and tickers and makes it difficult to recover tickers.

For example, company names that end with an "INC" suffix run into tickers, which are also capital letters. See my example below with "INC" and "AE".

[image: INC and AE]

Here is where I found the span tag:

[image: span tag]

Company tickers are 1 to 5 characters in length, and I have failed to regex tickers because there are many varieties of company suffixes (e.g., "INC", "CORP", "PLC", "SE", etc.), and not all company names have suffixes.

How can I either replace span tags with whitespace to separate company names and tickers or parse the span as another column?

Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime

def get_url(page=1, pageSize=50, assetType='stock'):
    if page == 1:
        return f'https://www.capitoltrades.com/trades?assetType={assetType}&pageSize={pageSize}'
    elif page > 1:
        return f'https://www.capitoltrades.com/trades?assetType={assetType}&page={page}&pageSize={pageSize}'
    else:
        return None

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(get_url(page=1))
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
time.sleep(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
table = pd.read_html(str(tables))[0]
driver.close()
```

Comment: You could easily write something to use the API which guarantees standard format and the tickers are in there E.g. https://bff.capitoltrades.com/trades?page=1&pageSize=15#  Looks like this person even wrote a Flask app for it: https://github.com/KonradIT/hilltrades

Comment: @QHarr Do you have documentation for this API? I had found an older SO answer with a different API URL, but I have not found any documentation on API limits, etc. I will have to learn what is a Flask app. :) Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure it is documented. I also couldn't find anything in ToS precluding scraping etc.  The author of the python wrapper automated with Flask but you don't need to. The link above returns trade info and has page size and page params. You play around to find max page size which, based on total items, will give you number of pages to increment the page param by in a loop of requests. The total items (irrespective of current page) is given in each response in the meta section. E.g. with the above param values currently meta reads "totalPages": 3022,
"totalItems": 45319.

Comment: The author at some point also submitted an update on GitHub to account for the API endpoint change IIRC.  API info also _"documented"_ via the js in this file (though not worth the effort at present to review I'd think): https://www.capitoltrades.com/_next/static/chunks/9619-347b39d52358e034.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To separate company names and tickers or parse the span as another column aka to get overall neat and clean `ResultSet`, you can change your tool selection strategy a bit.  In this case, It would be better to `apply bs4 with pandas DataFrame` instead of pd.read_html() method.

**Full working code as an example:**

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
#The base url: https://www.capitoltrades.com/trades?assetType=stock&pageSize=50
data = []
for page in range(1, 5):
    driver.get(f'https://www.capitoltrades.com/trades?assetType=stock&pageSize=50&page={page}')
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    for row in soup.select('table.q-table.trades-table > tbody tr'):
        Politician = row.select_one('[class="q-fieldset politician-name"] > a').text.strip()
        Politician_info = row.select_one('[class="q-fieldset politician-info"]').get_text(' ',strip=True)
        Traded_Issuer = row.select_one('[class="q-fieldset issuer-name"] > a').text.strip()
        Issuer_ticker =row.select_one('span[class="q-field issuer-ticker"]').text.strip()
        Published = row.select_one('[class="q-td q-column--pubDate"] .q-value').text.strip()
        Traded = row.select_one('[class="q-td q-column--txbDate"] .q-value')
        Traded = Traded.text.strip() if Traded else None
        Filed_after = row.select_one('[class="q-td q-column--reportingGap"] .q-value').text.strip()
        Owner =row.select_one('[class="svg-image owner-icon"]+span').text.strip()
        _type = row.select_one('[class="q-data-cell tx-type"]').get_text(strip=True)
        Size = row.select_one('[class="q-td q-column--value"] > div').get_text(strip=True)
        #Size = Size.text.strip() if Size else None
        Price =row.select_one('[class="q-field trade-price"]').text.strip()

        data.append({
            'Politician':Politician,
            'Politician_info':Politician_info,
            'Traded_Issuer':Traded_Issuer,
            'Issuer_ticker':Issuer_ticker,
            'Published':Published,
            'Traded':Traded,
            'Filed_after':Filed_after,
            'Owner':Owner,
            'Type':_type,
            'Size':Size,
            'Price':Price

        })


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                   Politician      Politician_info                 Traded_Issuer Issuer_ticker  ...        Owner  Type      Size   Price
0    Debbie Wasserman Schultz    Democrat House FL  ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY INC         AE:US  ...        Child  sell  1K - 15K   32.27     
1               Kathy Manning    Democrat House NC                         3M Co        MMM:US  ...       Spouse   buy  1K - 15K  108.95     
2               Kathy Manning    Democrat House NC                 Accenture PLC        ACN:US  ...       Spouse   buy  1K - 15K  250.07     
3               Kathy Manning    Democrat House NC                     Adobe Inc       ADBE:US  ...       Spouse  sell  1K - 15K  286.15     
4               Kathy Manning    Democrat House NC                  Alphabet Inc      GOOGL:US  ...       Spouse   buy  1K - 15K   97.56     
..                        ...                  ...                           ...           ...  ...          ...   ...       ...     ...       
195         Diana Harshbarger  Republican House TN                 CME Group Inc        CME:US  ...        Joint  sell  1K - 15K  176.26       
196         Diana Harshbarger  Republican House TN                 CME Group Inc        CME:US  ...       Spouse  sell  1K - 15K  176.26       
197         Diana Harshbarger  Republican House TN            The Home Depot Inc         HD:US  ...  Undisclosed  sell  1K - 15K  268.69       
198         Diana Harshbarger  Republican House TN            The Home Depot Inc         HD:US  ...  Undisclosed  sell  1K - 15K  268.69       
199         Diana Harshbarger  Republican House TN            The Home Depot Inc         HD:US  ...        Joint  sell  1K - 15K  268.69       

[200 rows x 11 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Btw, <sub>you don't need to go through those steps with `soup` and `find_all`   -   `read_html` already uses the same [or at least very similar] parsers as bs4 so you could just have</sub>

```py
table = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0] # , flavor='lxml')[0] # default
```

<sub>or even directly `pd.read_html(get_url(page=1))` - it [doesn't always work for all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74305179/web-scraping-using-pandas/74333634#74333634), but **it seems to work for *your* page**; it won't allow for the solutions I'm about to suggest, but I thought it was worth mentioning this convenience in case you didn't already know.</sub>

---

Anyway, my first solution is going to seem a bit hacky, but it has worked for me so far - since, `read_html` doesn't seem to have any string-separator argument like bs4's [`get_text`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) does, we can try to create the same effect by just adding spaces to the end of every tag in the html using `.replace`.

```py
table = pd.read_html(driver.page_source.replace('</', '&nbsp;</'))
```

---

If you are wary of messing with text-replace on html strings, or are worried about adding unwanted spaces (even though it *doesn't*, as far I have seen), or just want more control of how the text is extracted from table cells, you can also convert the bs4 `table` tag to a python dictionary using [`get_text`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) [with space (`' '`) separator] and [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

```py
tableSoup = soup.find('table')
tableHeaders = [
    h.get_text(' ', strip=True)
    for h in tableSoup.select('thead tr th')
]
tableData = [{h: c.get_text(' ', strip=True) for h, c in zip(
    tableHeaders, [cell for cell in r.select('td')]
)} for r in tableSoup.select('tbody tr')]
table = pd.DataFrame(tableData)
```

You could even replace `get_text` with your own function if you want to customize how cell values are extracted and/or processed, but as it is, it [and the first method with `.replace`] creates a DataFrame like:

| Politician | Traded Issuer | Published | Traded | Filed after | Owner | Type | Size | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pete Sessions Republican House TX | US TREASURY NOTE N/A | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 9 Nov | days 1 | Undisclosed | buy | 15K - 50K | N/A |
| Pete Sessions Republican House TX | US TREASURY NOTE N/A | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 7 Nov | days 3 | Undisclosed | buy | 50K - 100K | N/A |
| Pete Sessions Republican House TX | US TREASURY NOTE N/A | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 7 Nov | days 3 | Undisclosed | buy | 1K - 15K | N/A |
| Brad Sherman Democrat House CA | US TREASURY NOTE N/A | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 3 Nov | days 7 | Undisclosed | sell | 250K - 500K | N/A |
| Brad Sherman Democrat House CA | US TREASURY NOTE N/A | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 3 Nov | days 7 | Undisclosed | sell | 500K - 1M | N/A |
| Brad Sherman Democrat House CA | US TREASURY NOTE N/A | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 3 Nov | days 7 | Undisclosed | sell | 250K - 500K | N/A |
| Brad Sherman Democrat House CA | US TREASURY NOTE N/A | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 7 Nov | days 3 | Undisclosed | sell | 250K - 500K | N/A |
| Brad Sherman Democrat House CA | US TREASURY NOTE N/A | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 3 Nov | days 7 | Undisclosed | sell | 250K - 500K | N/A |
| Brad Sherman Democrat House CA | US TREASURY NOTE N/A | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 3 Nov | days 7 | Undisclosed | sell | 15K - 50K | N/A |
| Debbie Wasserman Schultz Democrat House FL | ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY INC AE:US | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 27 Oct | days 14 | Child | sell | 1K - 15K | 32.27 |
| Kathy Manning Democrat House NC | 3M Co MMM:US | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 12 Oct | days 29 | Spouse | buy | 1K - 15K | 108.95 |
| Kathy Manning Democrat House NC | Accenture PLC ACN:US | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 12 Oct | days 29 | Spouse | buy | 1K - 15K | 250.07 |
| Kathy Manning Democrat House NC | Adobe Inc ADBE:US | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 12 Oct | days 29 | Spouse | sell | 1K - 15K | 286.15 |
| Kathy Manning Democrat House NC | Alphabet Inc GOOGL:US | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 12 Oct | days 29 | Spouse | buy | 1K - 15K | 97.56 |
| Kathy Manning Democrat House NC | Amazon.com Inc AMZN:US | yesterday 14:05 | 2022 12 Oct | days 29 | Spouse | buy | 1K - 15K | 112.9 |

[Markdown for the table above was copied from the output of `print(table.drop([''], 'columns').to_markdown(index=False))`.]